# Where is scala-swing.jar in Ubuntu 16?

Tags: java, swing, scala, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

For the life of me, I can't locate a package containing the `scala-swing.jar` file anywhere in the Ubuntu repositories. What I tried:

```
apt search scala-swing
apt search scala | grep -i swing

apt-file search scala-swing.jar
apt-file search scala | grep -i swing
```

I got both the `scala` and `scala-library` packages duly installed, but none of them contains `scala-swing.jar` :(

And here are my sources :

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list | egrep -v "(^#.*|^$)" 
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial main restricted
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial universe
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial-updates universe
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial multiverse
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial-security main restricted
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial-security universe
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial-security multiverse
```

Apparently, back [in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS the file WAS present](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/scala-library/filelist) in the scala-library` package, but [no longer in the 16.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/scala-library/filelist) :( What is the right way to install this file?

Comment: scala-swing is no longer supported by the Scala developers. Considering that Ubuntu 16.04 is an LTS release that is supported until 2021, I'm guessing that Canonical didn't want to commit to supporting a library for 5 years that its own developers already abandoned.

Comment: Wow, the module does actually admit "mostly unsupported" https://github.com/scala/scala-swing I don't really know what that means. But it seems to me that anything moved to a module (like scala.sys will be) won't be part of an install.

Answer (score 2):

It's strange that you need this library as package and as unmanaged dependency. Anyway you can download it from [maven repository](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.scala-lang.modules%22%20scala-swing).